# How to focus on PhD

Tags: phd

In my third year of PhD but I started to lose focus. I now focus on other stuff such as learning to code and watching video tutorials on other stuff not related to my PhD. How can I focus on PhD and leave those?

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/procrastination

Comment: Don't spend too much time on academia.SX :-P

Comment: One thing that can help is to have in mind ''today I am doing X'', then you have something in mind as a target even if you don't do anything else apart from X.  Also going to the gym a few times a week.

Comment: I VTC'd because this is very much a thing dependent on the individual and details.

Answer (score 12):

You must understand that completing your PhD is the main priority.

1. One way to discipline yourself is to do some of your work in a library where you have no access to those distractions.
2. Set yourself daily targets and be consistent.
   Have a daily routine and be consistent with it.
3. I found working amongst other PhDs was a real boost and helped me retain focus.
4. Sometimes, just taking a break and going away for a few days just helps you to regain your momentum.

It can be difficult if you're also trying to secure a job in industry especially in your final year-a balance needs to be struck. If you're really struggling, speak to your advisor.

Answer (score 10):

There are a couple of possible reasons for your situation - maybe more. How you "fix" it depends on the nature of the problem, not the symptom. But all solutions probably involve other people.

If you are just bored, then you need to talk to your advisor to see how you can "juice" your research.

If you are dissatisfied with your topic then you need to give thought to whether you are in the right place with the right advisor.

If you are burned out (as is pretty common) then you need to find a way to clear your mind for some period(s) of time. I found cycling and other such physical activities to be an excellent way to "relax" so that I could focus better. Get a couple of people together for some joint activity that doesn't involve staring at screens but does get the blood flowing to your brain.

If you are actually depressed (I think that is hard to self diagnose) then you need to talk to a health professional to get yourself to a better place. Since it is hard to self diagnose it is probably worth scheduling an appointment to talk over your life situation. Being overly isolated in your life can have similar issues. Many universities provide a counseling department that can help or connect you with a health professional.

To "focus" on your degree doesn't mean 24/7. Attempting that can make you seriously crazy. Work toward a balanced life. And, IMO, aerobic exercise should be part of that.

Personal note: I went through burn-out and lost performance and focus. Changing universities and doing more aerobic things made a world of difference. Talking to a counsellor helped me see some things about myself that I didn't recognize. Any/all of these or other factors can hold you back.

Answer (score 5):

Neither other answer very clearly mentions the *revealed preferences* angle: one possibility for why you find yourself spending your time learning to code is that you are just more interested in coding, lately, than in your research. In particular, since learning to code is reasonably intellectually difficult, if you're making serious progress in it it's likely that you're not severely burnt out. Anyway, one option worth at least considering is whether it's really your Ph.D. that you want to focus on, rather than simply learning to code and getting a job in software. As has already been said, your Ph.D. is for *you*; if you would now prefer to do something else, there is nothing wrong with that, as long as you're not shying away from something you truly do want to do out of, say, fear of the challenge.

Comment: I would say the opposite: learning to code is easy and fun.

Comment: @andy256 Great, then you are lucky enough to enjoy and find easy something that qualifies you for the best job market in the history of the human species. It is of course absurd to make such a claim too broadly, or programmers would have a lot more competition!

Comment: Digressing from the OP's issue somewhat: I have been programming for 1/2 a century, taught programming to University Undergrads and Graduates for 20 years, and trained programmers in industrial settings. While I was expressing my personal experience above, here I will give my considered professional opinion: anyone of normal intelligence can learn to program. So I'm afraid I politely disagree with your "absurd" claim, although it does hinge on your definition of "too broadly".

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to answer this question. Every person has their own reasons and causes for procrastination and no one can recommend a universal answer that is applicable to every situation. But as someone who has been there* here are some general advice:

- Go easy on yourself. You might not feel as ambitious and productive as you were at the beginning and... that is okay. Most people feel this way after spending some time on a certain topic and it doesn't mean they are loosing control over their lives. One of the main causes of procrastination is the stress itself. And the irony is, it also leads to more stress which ends up in a positive feedback loop. So the moral of the story is: *Avoid stress*! (yes, that's easier said than done)
- Take a break. Sometimes procrastination is due to exhaustion. When you are working fruitlessly on something for so long, your brain feels trapped and seeks some kind of escape by forcing you to focus on something else. Although procrastination is itself a kind of break(!) but by taking a break I mean doing something that you feel having total control over it, and absolutely enjoy doing.
- Avoid being alone. It is much easier to avoid procrastination when you are doing teamwork and sharing your results and ideas with others. Even if you are doing a solo project, having some friends around and talking to them about what you are doing is often a great help.
- Divide and conquer. Our brain needs dopamine for its functioning. The problem with big and lengthy jobs such as getting a PhD is, their award and the resulting dopamine release will be granted much later. So in the short term, the brain seeks tiny doses of the damn hormone by forcing the focus on short-term goals, i.e. distractions. One hack to avoid this is to cut the big job into smaller pieces and rewarding yourself after finishing each piece.
- If you tried all you could and still feel the stress and observe a decline in your productivity, trapped inside a downward spiral of procrastination, seek professional help as fast as possible. Talk to a professional therapist or maybe talk to your professor. Most of them will know how you feel and hopefully, help you along the way to recovery.

Good luck and Godspeed!

<sub>* In fact, I would go as far to say that this is a universal phenomenon during the PhD years and it's really hard to find someone who hasn't experienced it.</sub>